# Odd javascript code execution order

Tags: javascript

Alright, first ever stack overflow question. I hope I do this right.

I'm trying to run this code:

```
    for(var i = 1; i < 17; i++){
    console.log("for loop runs. i is " + i);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("setTimeout runs. i is " + i);
        if(i < 3){
            $( ".example1" ).append( i );
            $( ".example2" ).append( i );
            $( ".example3" ).append( i );
            $( ".example4" ).append( i );
            $( ".example5" ).append( i );
        }
        else if(i<5){
            $( ".example1" ).append( i );
            $( ".example2" ).append( i );
            $( ".example3" ).append( i );
            $( ".example5" ).append( i );
        }
         else if(i<11){
            $( ".example1" ).append( i );
            $( ".example2" ).append( i );
            $( ".example3" ).append( i );
        }
        else if(i<15){
            $( ".example1" ).append( i );
            $( ".example3" ).append( i );           
        }
        else if(i<17){
            $( ".example1" ).append( i );
        }
    },200);
} //end for loop
```

And I'm getting this output in the console:

```
    for loop runs. i is 2
    for loop runs. i is 3
    for loop runs. i is 4
    for loop runs. i is 5
    for loop runs. i is 6
    for loop runs. i is 7
    for loop runs. i is 8
    for loop runs. i is 9
    for loop runs. i is 10
    for loop runs. i is 11
    for loop runs. i is 12
    for loop runs. i is 13
    for loop runs. i is 14
    for loop runs. i is 15
    for loop runs. i is 16
    (16) setTimeout runs. i is 17 // <---- runs 16 times
```

So the `for` loop runs and increments up to 17, then `setTimeout` runs 16 times. I don't understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution to:** Variable Not Having Expected Value When `setTimeout` Executes

Variable closure issue. IIFE to the rescue:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 17; i++){
  console.log("for loop runs. i is " + i);
  (function (ii) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("setTimeout runs. ii is " + ii);
      // the rest of your code goes here
    },200);
  }(i));
}
```

---

*Explanation:*

The reason you're getting the value "17" for `i` is because by the time the `setTimeout`s execute, `i` has been assigned the value "17" with the final iteration of the `for` loop. (`i` *has* to get set to "17" for the loop to terminate.) When you're handing `i` to the `setTimeout` function you're giving it a reference to `i`, *not* the current value of `i`.

Variable scopes are determined by the functions they are instantiated (`var`'d) in and upon execution of that function. `i` is (automatically) `var`'d upon preparing the `for` loop. So What "function" does the `for` loop live in? `window`, or the *global* scope. That is the scope of `i`. That is where `setTimeout` goes to get the value of `i` when it fires.

So, to solve the problem we need to instantiate a variable within a function and execute that function to lock in the value of that variable at that moment in the execution of the program.

Conceptually speaking, first, write a function, with one or more parameters:

```
function (x, y, z) {
  // stuff here
};
```

`x`, `y`, and `z` get var'd within this function scope when this function is executed.

Second, execute the function, passing necessary parameters:

```
function (x, y, z) {
  // stuff here
}(a, b, c);
```

`a`, `b`, and `c` have already been var'd, likely in the global scope, and now you're passing their current values to this function as parameters.

And third, wrap the function in parenthesis so the JavaScript interpreter treats it as a [function expression and not a function declaration](http://javascript.info/tutorial/functions-declarations-and-expressions).

```
(function (x, y, z) {
  // stuff here
}(a, b, c));
```

By the way, this works, too:

```
!function (x, y, z) {
  // stuff here
}(a, b, c);
```

...as does `~`, `+`, and `-`. You just need some benign operator at the beginning of the line to slap JS out of it's *function declaration* frenzy.

Kinda like the `for` loop, function parameter variables are automatically `var`'d  when the function is executed, but in this case the scope is within this function itself. So the *value* of `i` at the moment of execution in that line of code gets passed to the new variable `ii` inside the IIFE function and locked in to that function scope. Now, when `setTimeout` is finally ready to execute it looks to that function scope, rather than *global*, to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about closures in javascript. What is happening here is that multiple functions (closures) are created inside for loop all sharing same environment. By the time setTimeout function is called loop is finished iterating and i variable is always set to 17.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 0):

for loop runs 16 times, for i = 1 to 16 (as expected).
your setTimeout runs also 16 times as it inside same for cycle.

because your setTimeout function runs after 200 miliseconds, but 16 iterations of for cycle runs in fraction of that time, all setTimeouts runs long after for cycle ended when i is already set to be 17.

Comment: I don't think the second paragraph of your answer is correct. The setTimouts will always run at the end because the loop keeps the single thread busy. Try it with more iterations and a shorter timout

Comment: And I don't think, that you are wrong :)