# NodeJS scope issue

Tags: node.js

```
var std;
......
...... // here I fill std with some data
......
```

I'm trying to access the 'std' array while handling this route:

```
app.post('/saveABS',function(req,res){
var fileName = "./public/"+f;
fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(std, null, 4), function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The file was saved !");
        console.log(a);
        for(var i = 0; i < std.length; i++)
        {
            var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                host     : 'localhost',
                user     : 'root',
                password : 'admin' ,
                database : 'pfe'
            });
            console.log('before hr_cours = ' + std[i].hr_cours); // <========= WORKS
```

Here it displays the value of std[i].hr_cours correctly.

```
            if(std[i].hr_cours != a[i].hr_cours)
            {

                connection.connect(function(error){
                    console.log('after hr_cours = ' + std[i].hr_cours); // <============ undefined
```

Here it displays undefined.

```
                    if(error)
                    {
                        console.log('Unable to connect to database.');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("i= " + i);
                        console.log("I'm in : hr_cours = " + std[i].hr_cours);
                        connection.query("INSERT INTO assiste VALUES (CURDATE(),(SELECT id_etud FROM Etudiant WHERE nom_etud = ?),(SELECT s.id_seanceFROM Seance s, aura_lieu a, jour j, fait_objet fWHERE s.id_seance = a.id_seanceAND CURTIME() BETWEEN a.heure_debut AND a.heure_fin AND a.id_jour = j.id_jour AND j.dat = CURDATE() AND f.id_seance = s.id_seance AND f.id_ens = ?), ?)", [std[i].nom_etud, idEns, std[i].hr_cours], function(er1, res1){
                            if(er1)
                            {
                                console.log('Query error: ');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                console.log('success');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        res.end("all");
    }
});
});
```

I noticed that the issue is triggered once the execution flow enters the connection.connect block and that it's a scope issue; I searched everywhere for the answer but couldn't find a solution to my specific problem.
How can I make this work?

Comment: You might consider starting Node with `-harmony`, and using "let" instead of "var": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: I did... but same old error

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @DeveloperX - please upvote the two responses you found helpful, and please "accept" one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution of `connection.connect` is delayed and therefore when it fires `i` is not the same value as when a reference to `i` was passed in to it by the `for` loop. So, to lock in the value of `i` in that particular loop execution, wrap the `connection.connect` method and callback in an IIFE and pass `i` as it's parameter:

```
~function(i) {
    connection.connect(function(error){
        console.log('after hr_cours = ' + std[i].hr_cours);
        // other stuff
    })
}(i)
```

A more detailed explanation of IIFE's and scope closure in my answer here: [Odd javascript code execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124538/odd-javascript-code-execution-order/29124706#29124706)

And a JSFiddle playground to explore the technique: [IIFE Scope Closure With Pre-Existing Parameters](http://jsfiddle.net/h90dc9j4/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
app.post('/saveABS', function(req, res) {
    // ...
    for (var i = 0; i < std.length; i++) {                
        // ... 
        // This is SYNC. Here i = 0,1,2... 
        connection.connect(function(error) {
            // This is A-SYNC. 
            // Here i = std.length + 1  
            // always!
            // No matter even if it syntactically looks like i should be 1,2,3 according to the loop
            // but all of this is executed way after the loop has long been completed

            // ...
            // Here it displays undefined.
            console.log('after hr_cours = ' + std[i].hr_cours); // <============ undefined
```

A solution: Have a self executing anonymous function `(function(){})()` inside the loop and pass it the arguments (`i`) so that they will stay the same

```
for (var i = 0; i < std.length; i++) (function(i){
    connection.connect(function(error) {
        // ...
        // Here, since i is an argument passed to outer function
        // i will be i,2,3... 
})(i);
```

Another solution: `forEach` loop, which already has a callback function

```
std.forEach(function(currentValue, i, std){
    connection.connect(function(error) {
        // ...
        // Same here, since i is an argument passed to outer function
        // i will be i,2,3...     
        // Also currentValue = std[i] so you can use that 
});
```